# Rescale Segmentation on grid

Tags: matlab

Dear Matlab community,

I am looking for an elegant way to rescale outlines on a grid.
I have a segmentation of an image, which gives me a closed line. This segmentation is naturally evaluated on a grid since the image is 512:512. Hence, I have the segmentation in an array of dimensions (N,2), with the origin in the center of the mass of the segmentation.
I want to now rescale this segmentation (e.g. make it 20% smaller). I could just rescale each point of the segmentation by 0.8, but I would not have integer coordinates on the grid anymore. I could just use round to avoid this. The problem is that I then do not have a closed outline anymore, which is problematic since I want to use inpolygon afterwards.
I could go through the cumbersome task of eliminating degenerated points and interpolate missing points, but I am wondering if there is not a more elegant way to do rescaling of a closed outline on a grid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about applying a standard scaling image transformation? Do you access to imtransform (i.e. the image processing toolbox)?

Comment: Indeed, I could first rescale the image and then do the segmentation on this image. The problem here is that I am planing to iterate this process several times and that the segmentation is somewhat slow. Therefore I would prefer to work with the segmented outline.

Comment: No I mean rescale the "image of the grid", not the original image. Treat your segmentation as an image itself (a separate image).

Comment: This would actually work, thanks for the idea